# <select> Changing int to a string

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Working in AngularJS. All IDs being passed are int. However, after you select the option in the dropdown it comes back as a string. apologies for the formatting. New to asking questions on stack.

```
 <select style="width:95%" class="form-control" 
      ng-model=m.jurisdictionID data-value=x.jurisdictionID ng-change="buttonControll(); getFeeScheduleTips();">
      <option ng-repeat="x in m.jurisdictions | orderBy:'jurisdictionName'" ng-value={{x.jurisdictionID}}>{{x.jurisdictionName}}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: The HTML specification requires that all inputs are treated as strings. You'll need to convert them back to numbers if you need them as that type (something like `parseInt()` in JS).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added ParseInt() into the function on the ng-change and it worked like a charm.